# Form doesn't send email

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sendgrid

I am trying for the third time to post a problem with my file, hopefully, that someone will help me. I have a form on my index.html file. I Use express and Sendgrid to send user data to my email address after the form is submitted. The site is hosted on hosting and is live: https://liberamente.site

If we try to submit the form, we will get an error 404 and the email will not sent.
I think that the issue occurs on my server.js file. Presumably from the method app.get() or app.post()

This is my server.js file:

```js
// Send email after that form is submitted
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const path = require("path");
const router = express.Router();

// Import sendEmail function from utils/sendEmail
const sendEmail = require("./utils/sendEmail");

// Middleware
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

// view engine setup
app.set("view engine", "html");
app.engine("html", require("ejs").renderFile);

// Change views path folder
app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "/"));

// Use Static folder
app.use("/public", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));

app.use(
  "/public",
  express.static(path.join(__dirname + "public/css/style.css"))
);

app.use(
  "/public",
  express.static(path.join(__dirname + "public/fonts/fonts.css"))
);

app.use("/public", express.static(path.join(__dirname + "public/js/main.js")));

app.use("/", router);

// ---------------------------------------------------------------

//Create the route and render the index.html file
app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  res.render("index.html");
});

// ---------------------------------------------------------------

// Test the port
const PORT = process.env.port || 5500;
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on Port ${PORT}`));

app.post("/sendemail", (req, res) => {
  const { nome, email, telefono, data, deadline, messaggio, budget, gdpr } =
    req.body;

  const from = "Irene@liberamente.site";
  const to = "irenetestarella.it@gmail.com";

  const subject = "Nuovo Prospect";

  const output = `
  <p> Un nuovo prospect ha appena compilato il form sul sito Liberamente </p>

  <h3>Dettagli prospect: </h3>
  <ul>
      <li>Nome: ${nome} </li>
      <li>Email: ${email} </li>
      <li>Telefono: ${telefono} </li>
      <li>Data ed ora preferita: ${data} </li>
      <li>Deadline: ${deadline} </li>
      <li>Messaggio: ${messaggio} </li>
      <li>Budget: ${budget} </li>
      <li>Consenso informato GDPR: ${gdpr} </li>
  </ul>
  `;

  sendEmail(to, from, subject, output);
  res.redirect("/");
});
```

This is the screen of the error [image: Error]

This is the screen of my folder [image: Folder]

Any help will be really appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Rather than keep reposting, you should try some of these suggestions for getting more attention to your quesiton: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-one-of-my-own-questions-without-a-good-answer

Comment: I loaded your page and checked the source of the page, your contact form has an action attribute pointing to `https://formspree.io/f/xleakvwk`. What is this URL and what does it do?

Comment: Thank you for your help philnash but my hostinger plan doesn't support Nodejs so I have deleted the server.js file and I have tried another workaround. I am using Formspree. The action that you see is an endpoint of Formspree. I will study more accurately Express so for future project I will handle the form better! Thank you again